# Require WETH liquidity on uniswap v2 pair to be min 1 ETH to trade

Tags: solidity, uniswapv2

I want to launch a token with a significant part of the supply being airdropped (no vesting).

I'd like to implement a requirement so that airdropped holders won't sell into initial liquidity (1 ETH). Therefore, the token could not be swapped if WETH liquidity on the pair isn't >= 1 ETH.

I figured out a function that correctly retrieves WETH amount in the pair:

```
function getWethValueInPair() public view returns (uint256) {
    require(address(uniswapV2Pair) != address(0), "Uniswap V2 Pair address not set");

    // Get the reserves of the pair using the Uniswap V2 Router
    (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, ) = IUniswapV2Pair(uniswapV2Pair).getReserves();
    
        return uint112(reserve1);
}
```

However, when I try to add is as a requirement, it doesn't work (contract still compiles without errors though):

```
    Function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private lockTheSwap {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
                if (msg.sender != _taxWallet) {
 uint256 wethBalanceInPair = getWethValueInPair();
            require(wethBalanceInPair >= 1 ether, "Insufficient WETH in the pair");
                }
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Any idea why? What am I missing?

I know I'll eventually need a more complex solution that will also calculate the swap result ("if the swap results in less than 1 WETH in the pair, then do not swap" is the desired behavior), but wanted to figure out that simpler implementation first.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hopefully a silly question but you aren't testing this from an exempt wallet are you?
What addresses are exempt, which are you trying from, and can any hash of an example be shared?

Comment: Nope, I'm trying with a non exempt wallet I don't have hashes here, not on my computer right now

Comment: What's `wethBalanceInPair` value?